# SAS: merge in a do command

Tags: merge, set, sas

Say that I have the two following one row datasets:

```
data have_1;
input message $ order_num time price qty;
datalines;
A 3 34199 10 500 
run;

data have_2;
input message $ order_num time delete_qty ;
datalines;
B 2 34200 100 
run;
```

I have another dataset that aggregates previous order_numbers.

```
data total;
input order_num time price qty;
datalines;
1 34197 11 550
2 34198 10.5 450
run;
```

My objective is that I need to update the dataset `total` with the dataset `have_1` and `have_2` in a loop. When I start with `have_1`, a `message=A` implies that I have to update the dataset `total` by simply adding a new order to the `total` dataset. I must keep track the changes in the `total` datasets Hence the dataset `total` should look like this:

```
order_num time price qty id;
1 34197 11 550 1
2 34198 10.5 450 1
3 34199 10 500 1
```

Then, the dataset `total` needs to be updated with the dataset `have_2` where `message=B` implies that there is an update the `qty` to an `order_num` that is already in the the `total` datasets. I have to update the `order_num=2` by removing some of the `qty`. Hence, the `total` dataset should look like this:

```
order_num time price qty id;
1 34197 11 550 2
2 34198 10.5 350 2
3 34199 10 500 2
```

I have more than 1000 `have_` datasets which corresponds to each row in a another datasets. 
What's important is that I need to keep track of the changes in `total` for every messages with an `id`. Assuming that I have only `have_1` and `have_2`, then here's my tentative code:

```
%macro loop()
%do i=1 %to 2;

data total_temp;
set total; run;

data total_temp;
set have_&i;
if msg_type='A' then do;
set total have_&i;
drop message;
id=&i;
end;
if msg_type='B' then do;
merge total have_&i;
by order_num;
drop message;
qty=qty-delete_qty;
drop delete_qty;
id=&i
end;
run;

data total; set total_temp; run;

%end;
%mend;
%loop();
```

This code, say after the first loop, keeps only one line which corresponds to what's in `have_1`. Hence, can we use a `merge` and a `set` command in a `then do`? What's the proper code that I have to use?

The final datasets should look like this:

```
   order_num time price qty id;
    1 34197 11 550 1
    2 34198 10.5 450 1
    3 34199 10 500 1
    1 34197 11 550 2
    2 34198 10.5 350 2
    3 34199 10 500 2
```

Comment: If you have 1000 _have datasets, you are doing something wrong earlier than this step.  Sounds like you need to use the `by` statement instead of splitting into multiple datasets.

Comment: Yes @Joe I have this code done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this in a macro.  You CAN use a macro, but it will be slower.  Try this:

```
data have_1;
input message $ order_num time price qty;
datalines;
A 3 34199 10 500 
run;

data have_2(index=(order_num));
input message $ order_num time delete_qty ;
datalines;
B 2 34200 100 
run;

data total(index=(order_num));
input order_num time price qty;
datalines;
1 34197 11 550
2 34198 10.5 450
run;

/*First, add new orders*/
proc append base=total data=have_1(where=(message="A")) force;
run;

/*Now update for the deletions*/
data total;
modify total have_2(where=(message="B"));
by order_num;
qty = sum(qty,-delete_qty);
drop message delete_qty;
run;
```

Append the new order to the total data set with PROC APPEND.  This maintains the index and allows you to do the update through the MODIFY statement.

This could be done through two modify statements, though I find adding the new records through append to be clearer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I have no choice I believe to go through a Macro..that's my fault. I didn't explain my problem correctly and I updated my problem above. The reason why I need a macro is because I have over 1000 `have_` datasets. And I have to keep track the changes in the `total` datasets with `id`'s... any suggestions?

Comment: then just create the macro to loop over the code above for your data sets.

Comment: ahh I miss understood your code to begin with and yes you are right, just do a macro over your code and everything will work! (I think!) I will use your code inside a loop and if there is something wrong I will let you know but it should work out! Thanks!

Comment: np.  @joe is correct above.  Putting all the datasets together is best practice.  Good thing about the code I have here is that it will work with 1 or any number of observations in the input data sets.  You will probably find run times faster if you first concatenate your 1000+ sets into 2 sets (appends and updates).