# SAS: How not to overwrite a dataset when the "where" condition in a "Modify" statement does not hold?

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS code:

```
data have_1;
modify have_1 have_2(where=(message="X")) updatemode=nomissingcheck;
by reference;
qty=qty-canceled_qty; 
if qty=0 then delete; 
run;
```

This is within a loop and this implies that for my problem the dataset `have_2` changes for each loop iteration. The field entry `message` changes codes like "X", "A", "B"... the order arrival of messages mater. That is why I work within a loop that goes through the sequences of each message. Each message in `have_2` have different implications for `have_1`. The message "X" implies that I have to update the quantity to a specific reference number.

Therefore, I have a `modify` statement for each `message` inside the loop given that I don't know what is the order of message. How can I avoid SAS to overwrite my dataset `have_1` if, say in the example above, the `message` is not equal "X"?

This question is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949277/sas-merge-in-a-do-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How can I avoid SAS to overwrite my dataset..." - if you mean overwriting on record level - checking `_iorc_` value will give you control on what to do. You can add own logic to updates to the template code below.
Value for Not matched is "_DSENMR".

```
data have_1;
modify have_1 have_2(where=(message="X")) updatemode=nomissingcheck;
by reference;

    if      _iorc_ = %sysrc(_SOK) then do;
      * Update row ;
      replace;
    end;
    else if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_DSENMR) then do;
      * Add row ;
      output;
      _error_ = 0;
    end;
    else if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_DSEMTR) then do;
      * Multiple TRANSACTION data set observations do ;
      * not exist in MASTER data set ;
      _error_ = 0;
    end;
    else if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_DSENOM) then do;
      * No matching observation was found in MASTER data set ;
      _error_ = 0;
    end;
  run;
```

See more here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm