# An efficient way to update multiple columns using join

Tags: sas

I am really struggling with it guys.

The table needs to be updates has ~15M rows and ~200 columns.

I need to update few columns using a work table table.

This is (partly) what I need to do:

```
%macro condition;

%if &row_count>0 %then %do;

    data _null_;     
    set W4TWGKJ6 end=final;     
    if _n_ = 1 then call execute("proc sql  ;");     
    call execute
    ("update dds.insurance_policy set X_STORNO_BY_VERSION="||TOSNUM||" where     policy_no='"||cats(polid)||"' and X_INSURANCE_PRODUCT_CD='"||cats(prodid)||"' 
       and X_INSURER_SERIAL_NO = "||X_INSURER_SERIAL_NO||" and x_source_system_cd     ="||'"5"'||" and x_source_system_category_cd ="||'"5"'||" and x_current_ind     = "||'"Y"'||";,    

     update dds.insurance_policy set STATUS_CHANGE_DT="||ISSUE_DT||" where     policy_no='"||cats(polid)||"' and X_INSURANCE_PRODUCT_CD='"||cats(prodid)||"' 
       and X_INSURER_SERIAL_NO = "||X_INSURER_SERIAL_NO||" and x_source_system_cd     ="||'"5"'||" and x_source_system_category_cd ="||'"5"'||" and x_current_ind     = "||'"Y"'||";");    
    if final then call execute('quit;'); run;


%end;

%mend;

%condition;
```

I first check if there are rows in table (&row_count)
if there are,

I update 2 columns (I need to update 5, I just cut them from the example)
using a work table called W4TWGKJ6.

This update takes forever.
In fact, I stopped the process every single time, as it worked for hours without returning anything....

Does anyone knows a better solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Gal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `MODIFY` statement in datastep:
You should have same column names in both tables for BY variables and have them sorted by those variables.

```
data dds.insurance_policy;
   modify
         dds.insurance_policy
         W4TWGKJ6 (keep= POLICY_NO X_INSURER_SERIAL_NO /* key variables */ 
                       X_STORNO_BY_VERSION STATUS_CHANGE_DT /* ... other variables from source to update target */
         updatemode=nomissingcheck;
   by POLICY_NO X_INSURER_SERIAL_NO;

    if      _iorc_ = %sysrc(_SOK) then do;
      * Update row ;
      replace;
    end;
    else  _error_ = 0;
  run;
```

See [SAS: How not to overwrite a dataset when the "where" condition in a "Modify" statement does not hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996889/sas-how-not-to-overwrite-a-dataset-when-the-where-condition-in-a-modify-sta/18998383#18998383) for complete reference of *iorc* return values.

Comment: Thanks vasja,I was actually thinking of that option, problem is there are different names in transaction table...

Comment: So get them same in transaction table or e.g. create a dedicated view to have them same.